# yacc reduce/reduce conflict

Tags: parsing, yacc

I have the following grammar:

1. x: (z) o
2. x: n
3. z: x
4. z: z x
5. o: +|-|/|*
6. n: [0..9]

the parser stack currently is : "(z(zx"  the next tokens are )+)*

Which of the rules 3 or 4 is going the parser to reduce and why?

Thank you

Comment: Which ones are the terminal symbols? What rules are involved in the conflict? What's the message shown by YACC? This looks very much like a homework. Please refine your question.

Comment: yes it is a homework. The terminal symbols are 0..9 and +-/* . What I don't get is whether the parser will reduce x to z or zx to z. Probably the first one, because the rule z: x is first but I'm not sure.

Comment: The output from `yacc -v` will tell you what the grammar does (or `bison -v`).

Comment: There's no reduce/reduce conflict here -- why do you think there is?

Comment: So, you say that rule 3 will be reduced and there is no conflict with rule 4?

Comment: @mschonaker When given a grammar, you can simply assume that the terminal symbols are those which do not produce anything (do not appear on the left side of a rule). For instance an `x` generates `n`, so `x` is nonterminal. But an `n` does not generate anything so it is a terminal symbol.

Comment: I added the [homework] tag since "yes it is a homework".

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: rule 4.

Intuitively, this is because rules 3 and rules 4 are a left-associative pair that converts X's to Z in a greedy way.

Another reason is that if we reduce rule 3, we end up with Z Z on the parsing stack, which is not a possible sentential form. The grammar does not generate partial derivations that have Z Z.